# How to group Pandas data frame by column with regex match

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','b','c','d','e'],
                   'XX_111_S5_R12_001_Mobile_05':[-14,-90,-90,-96,-91],
                   'YY_222_S00_R12_001_1-999_13':[-103,0,-110,-114,-114],
                   'ZZ_111_S00_R12_001_1-999_13':[1,2.3,3,5,6],
})

df.set_index('id',inplace=True)
df
```

Which looks like this:

```
Out[6]:
    XX_111_S5_R12_001_Mobile_05  YY_222_S00_R12_001_1-999_13  ZZ_111_S00_R12_001_1-999_13
id
a                           -14                         -103                          1.0
b                           -90                            0                          2.3
c                           -90                         -110                          3.0
d                           -96                         -114                          5.0
e                           -91                         -114                          6.0
```

What I want to do is to group the column based on the following regex:

```
\w+_\w+_\w+_\d+_([\w\d-]+)_\d+
```

So that in the end it's grouped by `Mobile`, and `1-999`.

What's the way to do it. I tried this but fail to group them:

```
import re
grouped = df.groupby(lambda x: re.search("\w+_\w+_\w+_\d+_([\w\d-]+)_\d+", x).group(), axis=1)
for name, group in grouped:
    print name
    print group
```

Which prints:

```
XX_111_S5_R12_001_Mobile_05
YY_222_S00_R12_001_1-999_13
ZZ_111_S00_R12_001_1-999_13
```

What we want is `name` prints  to:

```
Mobile
1-999
1-999
```

And `group` prints the corresponding data frame.

Comment: Could you give some additional details about what you are trying to achieve? It looks like you are trying to output 3 groups in your groupby, when the original dataframe only has 3 columns anyway. Furthermore, by definition of a groupby, the group names/labels (which you've called `name`) are unique, so the desired output you described is just not possible; the closest thing would be to create a row of labels (i.e. Mobile and 1-999) and use those in your groups instead, but I'm not sure if this is relevant to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) on the columns in order to [extract substrings](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#extracting-substrings) for your `groupby`:

```
# Performing the groupby.
pat = '\w+_\w+_\w+_\d+_([\w\d-]+)_\d+'
grouped = df.groupby(df.columns.str.extract(pat, expand=False), axis=1)

# Showing group information.
for name, group in grouped:
    print name
    print group, '\n'
```

Which returns the expected groups:

```
1-999
    YY_222_S00_R12_001_1-999_13  ZZ_111_S00_R12_001_1-999_13
id                                                          
a                          -103                          1.0
b                             0                          2.3
c                          -110                          3.0
d                          -114                          5.0
e                          -114                          6.0 

Mobile
    XX_111_S5_R12_001_Mobile_05
id                             
a                           -14
b                           -90
c                           -90
d                           -96
e                           -91
```

Answer (score 1):

After grouping, set the index of the new dataframe to `[re.findall(r'\w+_\w+_\w+_\d+_([\w\d-]+)_\d+', col)[0] for col in df.columns]` (which is `['Mobile', '1-999', '1-999']`).

Comment: Looks like I overlooked your question, based on the wrong description. The problem that you have is not related to grouping. It is related to indexing.

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues with your regex, `\w` matches word characters which include underscore, and that doesn't seem like what you want, if you just want to match letters and digits, using `A-Za-z0-9-` would be better:

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str.extract("([A-Za-z0-9-]+)_\d+$"), axis=1).sum()
```

[image]