# Sum all counts when their fuzz.WRatio > 90 otherwise leave intact

Tags: python-3.x, fuzzywuzzy, fuzzy-comparison, python-re

What I want to do was actually group by all similar strings in one columns and sum their 
corresponding counts if there are similarity, otherwise, leave them.
A little similar to this post. Unfortunately I have not been able to apply this to my case:
[How to group Pandas data frame by column with regex match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036645/how-to-group-pandas-data-frame-by-column-with-regex-match)

Unfortunately, I ended up with the following steps:

I wrote a function to print out all the fuzz.Wratio for each row of string,
when each row does a linear search from the top to check if there are other similar
strings in the rest of the rows. If the WRatio > 90, I would like to sum these row's
corresponding counts. Otherwise, leave them there.

I created a test data looking like this:

```
test_data=pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['Apple.Inc.','apple.inc','APPLE.INC','OMEGA'],
    'count':[4,3,2,6]
})
```

So what I want to do is make the result as a dataframe like:

```
result=pd.Dataframe({
    'Nname':['Apple.Inc.','OMEGA'],
    'Ncount':[9,6]
})
```

My function so far only gave me the fuzz ratio for each row,
and to my understanding is that,
each row compares to itself three times( here we have four rows).
So My function output would look like:

```
pd.Dataframe({
    'Nname':['Apple.Inc.','Apple.Inc.','Apple.Inc.','apple.inc',\
    'apple.inc','apple.inc'],
    'Ncount':[4,4,4,3,3,3],
    'FRatio': [100,100,100,100,100,100] })
```

This is just one portion of the whole output from the function I wrote with this test data.
And the last row "OMEGA" would give me a fuzz ratio about 18.

My function is like this:

```
def checkDupTitle2(data):
    Nname=[]
    Ncount=[]
    f_ratio=[]

    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        current=0
        count=0
        space=0
        for space in range(0, len(data)-1-current):
            ratio=fuzz.WRatio(str(data.loc[i]['name']).strip(), \
                        str(data.loc[current+space]['name']).strip())
            Nname.append(str(data.loc[i]['name']).strip())
            Ncount.append(str(data.loc[i]['count']).strip())
            f_ratio.append(ratio)
            df=pd.DataFrame({
                'Nname': Nname,
                'Ncount': Ncount,
                'FRatio': f_ratio
            })
    return df
```

So after running this function and get the output,
I tried to get what I eventually want.
here I tried group by on the df created above:

```
output.groupby(output.FRatio>90).sum()
```

But this way, I still need a "name" in my dataframe,
how can I decide on which names for this total counts, say, 9 here.
"Apple.Inc" or "apple.inc" or "APPLE.INC"?

Or, did I make it too complex?
Is there a way to group by "name" at the very first and treat "Apple.Inc.", "apple.inc" and "APPLE.INC" all the same, then my problem has solved. I have stump quite a while. Any helps would be highly
appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is the intended outcome when there are multiple elements that are pretty similar to each other. Your example shows that you basically want to remove duplicates and create the sum for these two elements. However you might run into a case where you have [a, b, c] with a being similar to b, b being similar to c, but a not being similar to c (below 90%)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, so my function actually ran a linear search that for each loop, the current would compare with the current+space, where space is from 1 to the last one in the data frame. This took a lot of time but I did not come up with better solution. Yeah my end goal is to sum all similar one's counts and leave others not similar ones intact. Thanks!

Comment: What about the second part of my question? You could have `[a, b, c]` with `b` being very similar both to `a` and `c`, but `a` and `c` having a similarity of below 90%. In this case the question arrises to which sum it should be added.

Comment: I understand, so later what I am thinking is, let a compare with b, and c linearly, if any ratio > 90, sum up their counts, a would go with b and  then a would go with c, then b goes to c, as we do not have to let b goes with a again. so from the top go to the end. this is my thought.

Comment: Or maybe we can see this question in another way, is there a way to group "APPLE.INC", "apple.inc." and "Apple.inc" together? such as transform them to certain data types to work around upper case, lower case and punctuation? As long as I can make them all the same, I can just group them and sum up their counts.

Comment: so your always working with exact matches? (after lowercasing and removing punctuation)

Comment: well, I just want similar ones to sum up and unique ones in the current data set (now it is small but it can be very big) remain intact. Just like you do a group by in pandas then add a sum() unique ones would sum up. My question here is to loose that restriction of exact match to fuzz ratio > 90 or other threshold I set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is using my library [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/rapidfuzz) instead of FuzzyWuzzy since it is faster and it has a process method `extractIndices` which does help here. This solution is quite a bit faster, but since I do not work with pandas regulary I am sure there are still some things that could be improved :)

```py
import pandas as pd
from rapidfuzz import process, utils

def checkDupTitle(data):
    values = data.values.tolist()
    companies = [company for company, _ in values]
    pcompanies = [utils.default_process(company) for company in companies]
    counts = [count for _, count in values]

    results = []
    while companies:
        company = companies.pop(0)
        pcompany = pcompanies.pop(0)
        count = counts.pop(0)

        duplicates = process.extractIndices(
            pcompany, pcompanies,
            processor=None, score_cutoff=90, limit=None)

        for (i, _) in sorted(duplicates, reverse=True):
            count += counts.pop(i)
            del pcompanies[i]
            del companies[i]
        results.append([company, count])

    return pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Nname','Ncount'])

test_data=pd.DataFrame({
    'name':['Apple.Inc.','apple.inc','APPLE.INC','OMEGA'],
    'count':[4,3,2,6]
})

checkDupTitle(test_data)
```

The result is

```py
pd.Dataframe({
    'Nname':['Apple.Inc.','OMEGA'],
    'Ncount':[9,6]
})
```

Comment: This looks great! Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Really intelligent! Just some feedback that I am running it and it seems not able to tolerate much bigger size than say, more than 50 rows of data set. Just my experience running it now. But still brilliant.

Comment: Whats happening on bigger sizes? Is it just to slow?

Comment: It is alright now after I used my organization's VPN. I guess it was just my home network issues. The kernel died earlier in Jupyter notebook. Now it should be good. Thanks! This is really great work!

Comment: I did just test this and realised that in my last release the performance got a lot less good, so I fixed this. I did update the answer aswell so preprocessing is only done once, so it should be a lot faster now

Comment: Thanks a billion!! I'll try this:)